# heap-use-after-free error in Question Remove Duplicates From an Unsorted Linked List(Leetcode 1836)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linked-list

The question is asking for **deleting all the nodes whose values are not unique** in the list. For example, input **1->2->1->2->3** should output **3** only

The solution works fine in both my local IDEs and Online Compilers. But I got the error on LeetCode.

My code is failing the test case with the error

```
================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x602000000178 at pc 0x000000374efd bp 0x7ffdccb2bd60 sp 0x7ffdccb2bd58
READ of size 8 at 0x602000000178 thread T0
```

If I comment out `delete toDelete;` in `deleteNode(ListNode*)`, then the error goes away.

Here's the question https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list/

Here is my solution

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
private:
    //Delete the next node and return its value
    int deleteNode(ListNode* prevToDelete)
    {
        //Assume prevToDelete has next node
        ListNode* toDelete = prevToDelete->next;
        prevToDelete->next = toDelete->next;
        delete toDelete;
        
        return (prevToDelete->next)?prevToDelete->next->val:-1;
    }
    
public:
    ListNode* deleteDuplicatesUnsorted(ListNode* head) {
        
        //Add Dummy Head to the list
        ListNode* dummy{new ListNode(0, head)};
        ListNode* prev{dummy}, *cur{};
        
        //Map to store value-Node-hit pair
        unordered_map<int, pair<ListNode*, bool>> map;
        
        int val{};
        while((cur = prev->next))   //Until tail node
        {
            val = cur->val;
            //Duplicate values exist, delete current node
            if(map.count(val))
            {
                deleteNode(prev);
                map[val].second = true; //Flag to indicate the node needed to be deleted later
            }
            else
            {
                //Add new cur_value-prev_node-hit pair into the map
                map.insert({val, {prev, false}});
                
                //Update prev node
                prev = cur;
            }
        }
        
        //Remove remaining nodes hit in the map
        for(auto mit = map.begin(); mit != map.end(); mit++)
        {
           
            //If it has been hit before
            if(mit->second.second)
            {    
                int value = deleteNode(mit->second.first);
                //if any node in the map is the oen just deleted, update it
                if(map.count(value))
                    map[value].first = mit->second.first; 
                
            }
        }
        
        //Update head and delete dummy
        head = dummy->next;
        delete dummy;
        
        return head;
    }
};
```

Comment: Are **you** using the address sanitizer in your local/online builds? If not, start now.

Comment: Those of us who are not subscribed to leetcode premium cannot view the question.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Is this supposed to remove every occurance of elements that occur multiple times in the list? That's what you're doing after all. Otherwise a set would do to detect elements that already occured. Furthermore checking for a mapping and inserting one can be done in one go: `auto insertResult = map.try_emplace(val, prev, false); if (!insertResult.second) { insertResult.first->second.second = true; }` Also using `new` and `delete` for `dummy` are unnecessary: Just allocate it on the stack: `ListNode dummy(0, head); ListNode* prev = &dummy;`.

Comment: `deleteNode()`does not "return its value". So either your code is wrong or your comment. You also can not delete the first element in a list. Arguably you never need to since the first element can never be a duplicate. But still bad style.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow The question asks for deleting all nodes whose values are not unique in the list.  [1,1,2,2] will be [].

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow The question is asking for deleting all the nodes whose values are not unique in the list. So **1->1** will be an empty list. `deleteNode(ListNode*)` returns the value of the node just been deleted to check if any entry in the map has a dangling pointer after.

Comment: @aOtf_ Ups, I misread that as only removing the duplicates. So `deleteNodes` needs to be fixed so it can delete the first node. Luckily the change is the addition of a single `*`. Of have it return the new front of the (sub)list.

Comment: `deleteNode(ListNode*)` returns the value of the value of the node AFTER the deleted one.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow  Sorry I don't fully understand the idea. Did you mean to return the int value of the node after the deleted one(**int**), or to return a copy of the node after the deleted one(**ListNode**)? Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244923/discussion-between-aotf-and-goswin-von-brederlow).